# TypeScript Next JS

Tags: typescript, postgresql, next.js, prisma, formik

Hello I'm in need of help this is my API in .ts I want to create a client-side code for this wherein user will be able to edit or update their information by filling up fields and submitting them. it should also be in formik please help

```
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";
import prisma from "../../prisma/handlePrisma";

export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
) {
  try {
    const { studentNumber, firstName, middleName, lastName, extensionName, birthdate, sex, program, educStatus, schoolYear, section, emailAddress, contactNumber, address } = req.body;

    // Retrieve the applicant data based on the provided studentNumber
    const applicantData = await prisma.applicant.findUnique({
      where: { studentNumber },
    });

    if (!applicantData) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: "Applicant not found" });
    }

    // Update the applicant data
    const updatedApplicant = await prisma.applicant.update({
      where: { studentNumber },
      data: {
        firstName: firstName || applicantData.firstName,
        middleName: middleName || applicantData.middleName,
        lastName: lastName || applicantData.lastName,
        extensionName: extensionName || applicantData.extensionName,
        birthdate: birthdate || applicantData.birthdate,
        sex: sex || applicantData.sex,
        program: program || applicantData.program,
        educStatus: educStatus || applicantData.educStatus,
        schoolYear: schoolYear || applicantData.schoolYear,
        section: section || applicantData.section,
        emailAddress: emailAddress || applicantData.emailAddress,
        contactNumber: contactNumber || applicantData.contactNumber,
        address: address || applicantData.address,
      },
    });

    // Return the updated applicant data as a response
    return res.status(200).json(updatedApplicant);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what issue you are facing?

Comment: I can't figure out how I'll implement it to my client-side code. I want to have fields and when they enter data on it it'll update the prisma.schema database. using formik